# One of five services sharing an account gets logon failure

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, windows-service

We had a recent servercrash due to power failure. Five servers went down instantly (no soft shutdown). After getting the power back, we restarted them and everything works well except that now the service `SQL Server Analysis Service` does not start because of logon failure (Error 1069).

The service account in question is shared by four other`SQL-services and they have started without trouble. To add injury to insult, the password of the account is randomly set during an automated install of the whole server (including SQL). Thus makes it impossible, short of hacking, to find out what the actual password is.

Is reinstallation out only option now?

Comment: Do you mean the same password is used to start four other services on the same server, or the same service on four other servers? Either way, why can't you change the password for the service account and set the service to use it?

Comment: Well, since it's the same account for all five services it's also the same password.

Comment: I was asking if the services were all on one server or scattered across five servers. Reading again, it looks like it's the former. Either way, any reason why you can't change the account's password and then update each service to use the new password?